# Custom search box query for homepage

Tags: search, joomla-3.9

I'm really new to Joomla and I have some basic experience with HTML/PHP and mySQL

I have a seperate DB in mySQL which has only 1 table & 3 fields to be populated, this part I've already setup and filled with information.
What I can't figure out is how to get a searchbox to appear on the homepage of my joomla site that is only for searching this DB and not the whole website (which I don't require)

If anyone is able to give me some guidance that would be really appreciated.

The idea is a user would search for a code which is populated in my "SearchCode" column of the table and then I need the response to come back with everything from the 3 columns for the row that contains that code (I appreciate that's probably pretty obvious but I want to be clear)

I don't need anything fancy, I can figure a lot of myself once I know the basics of how to get the search box into the main page.

Comment: You can output the form via a Joomla custom module (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1vsC3ss1Q4), not a problem. But you need to post the form to some backend. I'd develop an ajax endpont (Joomla module Ajax would fit you) which should perform the DB request and return data to your frontend.

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface
I've forgotten to point to this link

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into those, I did have a look at Ajax briefly so that definatly seems like the best option.

Comment: @AHe thank you for offering your support, however you are providing potentially resolving advice as a comment and this does not comply with this site's Q&A format.  Although you have already earned your [tag:informed] badge, you may like to revisit the [tour] page.  Since you are not seeking question clarification, please transfer your comments to a new answer.

Comment: @Sho Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 0):

> As per @mickmackusa note copy my comment here

You can output the form via a Joomla custom module ([youtube.com/watch?v=a1vsC3ss1Q4](https://youtube.com/watch?v=a1vsC3ss1Q4)), not a problem. But you need to post the form to some backend. I'd develop an ajax endpont [docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface) (Joomla module Ajax would fit you) which should perform the DB request and return data to your frontend